# proving that a certain function is absolutely continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let's consider positive real numbers $\alpha,\beta>0$. Then let's define the function:

$ f(x)= x^{\alpha} sin(\frac{1}{x^\beta})$ if $x\in (0,1]$.

$f(0)=0$.

Prove that if $\alpha>\beta>0$ then $f$ is absolutely continuous. 
I was Reading the solution of Kaczor, he said that it's because:
$$
f\left( x \right) = \int\limits_0^x {\alpha t^{\alpha  - 1} \sin \left( {\frac{1}
{{t^\beta  }}} \right) - \beta t^{\alpha  - \beta  - 1} \cos \left( {\frac{1}
{{t^\beta  }}} \right)} 
$$
and the integrand is integrable on $[0,1]$. But I don't know how to prove that :S. At least in the case $\alpha - \beta \ge 1$ , then it's easy to see that is in fact continuous, but in a general case I don't know if it's true :S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the two parts of the sum of the integral has the form $x^{-r}$ times a bounded function, where $r$ is less than 1. Then the absolute value of each part is bounded above by $Cx^{-r}$, which is integrable. Since the absolute value has a bounded integral, each part is integrable. Since each is integrable, their difference is integrable.